# : mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am working on a simple practice application for using hibernate. It has simple mapping like a manufacturer can have many mobiles. But a mobile can only be manufactured by single manufacturer. Here is what I think the code should be.

```
package mobileconsumers.entity.dto;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name="ms_ref_mobile")
public class MobileDTO {

private Long id;
private String model;
private ManufacturerDTO manufacturerDTO;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="MOBILE_ID")
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getModel() {
    return model;
}
public void setModel(String model) {
    this.model = model;
}
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="MANUFACTURER_ID")
public ManufacturerDTO getManufacturer() {
    return manufacturerDTO;
}
public void setManufacturer(ManufacturerDTO manufacturer) {
    this.manufacturerDTO = manufacturer;
}


}
```

this is the second dto

```
package mobileconsumers.entity.dto;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="ms_ref_manufacturer")
public class ManufacturerDTO {

private Long id;
private String name;
private Set<MobileDTO> mobileDTOs = new HashSet<>(0);

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="MANUFACTURER_ID")
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
@Column(name="NAME")
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="manufacturerDTO")
public Set<MobileDTO> getMobileDTOs() {
    return mobileDTOs;
}
public void setMobileDTOs(Set<MobileDTO> mobileDTOs) {
    this.mobileDTOs = mobileDTOs;
}


}
```

When I try to start my server it gives me an error saying..
`org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference anunknown target entity              property: mobileconsumers.entity.dto.MobileDTO.manufacturerDTO in   mobileconsumers.entity.dto.ManufacturerDTO.mobileDTOs`
The mapping seems to be fine to me. there must be something really silly that I am missing out. Just needed fresh pair of eyes to look at my code and figure out whats going wrong..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change `mappedBy` value, so that it refers the `manufacturer` property on the `@ManyToOne` side of the association:

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="manufacturer")
public Set<MobileDTO> getMobileDTOs() {
    return mobileDTOs;
}
```

Comment: Yes that worked. and the answer below told me why. I think i did something wrong while creating getters and setters. Thank you very much..